# warning for int to long

Tags: gcc

is there a option in gcc compiler/ pclint for error/warning for int to long conversion.

Comment: Why would there be? There cannot possibly be a loss of precision.

Answer (score 2):

Int to long should be OK. For long to int see , `-Wconversion`:

```
int main() {
    long long l = 0;
    int n = l;
}
```

then

```
gcc -Wconversion wc.c
```

gives:

```
wc.c:3: warning: conversion to 'int' from 'long long int' may alter its value
```